# Как показать изображении в C# MVC 5?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, изображения

[image]
Этот код  работает в Visual Studio Code но не работает в Visual Studio. Скажите пожалуйста. Почему в место изображения показывается проста ее место?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: место показывает потому что браузер не может получить доступ к файлу. А по хорошему почитайте не много мат части по созданию статических веб сайтов для начала и разберитесь что такое относительные и абсолютные пути

Comment: Когда страница через веб-сервер открывается, браузер не имеет прямого доступа к диску. Иначе любой сайт смог бы шариться у вас в компе. А VS Code видимо просто как файл открывает, а не через сервер.